# Normals acting weird

Tags: normals

[image]

I've been modeling these buttons, and the middle one keeps having this weird shading, like there was something wrong with its normals.

[image: Weird shading]

I've checked them and they seem to be ok, but the shading problem persists, unless I purposefully flip the normals of the faces framing the 3 buttons.

[image: Normals seem to be ok]
[image: Vertex normals also seem to be all right]
[image: Some normals flipped]
[image: Face Orientation]

Once they face in the wrong direction, the shading issue goes away, but the flipped polygons would cause problems down the road, so I really want to fix them.

I've tried smoothing, recalculating, and setting them from the faces, to no avail. I have no modifiers or anything on the mesh.

Does anyone have any idea what's at play here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*, hard to guess how you messed up the split normals though:

[image]